# In Sublime Text 3 Vintage Mode, using semicolon to find next result in 'f' motion does not work

Tags: vim, sublimetext3

I'm using Vintage Mode in Sublime Text 3 on OS X 9.0.

In Vim, pressing f and then any character searches for the next instance of that character on the same line. I can then press ; to continue searching for the next instance of that character on that line. The , key does the same thing but in the opposite direction.

Neither of these commands function in Vintage Mode.

How can I bind those actions (next instance of character, previous instance of character) to ; and , ? Or is there an alternative hotkey in Sublime for some reason?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't know about the built in vintage, but you may be interested in using [Vintageous](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous). It's much more feature complete (in my opinion) than the included vintage mode.

Comment: Vintageous solves my problem perfectly. Thanks. To anyone installing Vintageous: Make sure you disable Vintage Mode by going to Sublime Text menu->Preferences->Settings - User. Then add "Vintage" to the list of ignored packages.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the answer by Benjamin.

In Sublime 3, Vintage is already in the ignored_packages list
(if you look in Sublime Text menu->Preferences->Settings - Default)

However, this is how you would do it.

```
{
    "ignored_packages": ["Vintage"]
}
```

Comment: Kumar, good information. However, for supplemental information such as this, I suggest that next time you just add it as a comment to the answer itself. That keeps it associated and from being overlooked -- as many people just read the accepted answer. I'd upvote the comment. :)

Answer (score 4):

Updating to the [latest Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) build (3083 right now) fixes this problem with Vintage mode. Now <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> work as expected.